# audit log reason showing as [object Object] when kicked

Tags: discord, discord.js

when i kick a user with this command the audit logs show [object Onject] rather than the reason. if i were to replace all instances of kick in this command with ban it would work fine, but for some reason it's just kick where this issue occurs.
any ideas?

```
       const caseInsensitive = message.content.toLowerCase();
       const arguments = caseInsensitive.substring(prefix.length).split(` `);
       const mention = message.mentions.users.first();
       const member = message.guild.member(mention);
       const reason = (!arguments[2]) ? `none` : `${arguments[2]}`

        case `kick`:
            if (!message.member.hasPermission(`KICK_MEMBERS`)) return;
            if (!arguments[1]) return message.channel.send(`specify user`)
            if (!mention) return message.channel.send(`couldn't find user`)
            if (message.author === mention) return message.channel.send(`don't commit suicide`)
            if (!member.kickable) return message.channel.send(`can't kick user`)
            member.kick({ reason: `${reason}` }).then(
                message.channel.send(`user has ben korked`))
            break;
```

Comment: before you kick the member, log what reason is.

Comment: try using JSON.stringify() that object and see if you can find the reason it may contain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the problem.

You're passing an object into the `member.kick()` function.

According to the documentation, the parameters are supposed to be `member.kick(reason)`, not `member.kick({ reason })`.

Hope this helps.